# Add/remove tags on frontend programmatically

Tags: tags, front-end

I generated a link on the frontend toolbar to feature a post (adding the 'featured' tag). It works OK adding or removing, but the problem is showing the post. When removing the tag and then using the_tags() or has_tags() on the template, the post still seems to have it; I have to refresh the page to see the result.

But when adding the tag, everything works as expected: the term is added and the tag is showed with a simple clic.

What am I doing wrong? Could be the action hook? Is there any type of cache?

```
function toolbar_add_link( $wp_admin_bar )
{
  if ( is_single() )
  {
    $title = '';
    $url = '';

    if ( has_tag( 'featured' ) )
    {
      $title = '<span style="top: 2px;" class="ab-icon dashicons-heart"></span> ' . __( 'No destacar', 'the_textdomain' );
      $url = wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( 'the_action', 'remove_feature_post' ), 'prefix-remove_feature_post' );
    }
    else
    {
      $title = '<span style="top: 2px;" class="ab-icon dashicons-heart"></span> ' . __( 'Destacar evento', 'the_textdomain' );
      $url = wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( 'the_action', 'add_feature_post' ), 'prefix-add_feature_post' );
    }

    $args = array(
      'id'    => 'feature-post',
      'title' => $title,
      'href'  => $url,
      'meta'  => array(
        'class' => 'dashicons-edit'
      ),
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'toolbar_add_link', 999 );


function add_remove_tags()
{
  global $post;

  $action = isset( $_GET['the_action'] ) ? $_GET['the_action'] : '';
  $wpnonce_action = 'prefix-' . $action;

  if ( ! ( isset( $_GET['_wpnonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['_wpnonce'], $wpnonce_action ) && ( current_user_can( 'editor' ) || current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) ) )
  {
    //echo 'invalid nonce';
    return;
  }

  $term = term_exists( 'featured', 'post_tag ');
  $tag_id = null;

  if ( is_array( $term ) )
  {
    $tag_id = (int) $term['term_id'];
  }

  /*
   * If this was coming from the database or another source, we would need to make sure
   * these where integers:

  $cat_ids = array_map( 'intval', $cat_ids );
  $cat_ids = array_unique( $cat_ids );

   */

  if ( $_GET['the_action'] === 'add_feature_post' ) 
  {
    wp_add_object_terms( $post->ID, $tag_id, 'post_tag' );
  }
  elseif ( $_GET['the_action'] === 'remove_feature_post' )
  {
    wp_remove_object_terms( $post->ID, $tag_id, 'post_tag' );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'add_remove_tags' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution in https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L0

wp_add_object_terms() uses wp_cache_delete(), but wp_remove_object_terms() don't. Just added this:

```
wp_remove_object_terms( $post->ID, $tag_id, 'post_tag' );
wp_cache_delete( $object_id, 'post_tag_relationships' );
```